# When LASSO selects only parts of a categorical variable?

Tags: regression, lasso, regularization, categorical-encoding, regression-strategies

I want to use LASSO to construct a model and then run a logistic regression on the variables LASSO selects. However, LASSO selects only parts of some categorical variables that I put into it.

Does that mean I should dichotomize the categorical variables and only use those that LASSO selected or should I include the entire categorical variable in my regression model?

Comment: You should try group lasso.  The categorical variable can be selected as a whole using this method

Comment: Just like running individual testing on coefficients that are really part of a larger categorical variable, it is nonsensical to do so and remove the "parts" that a "test" doesn't "pick" (you first would use a joint test of all coefficients for that variable before considering individual tests, and even still, you wouldn't generally remove portions that aren't "picked" by the test or algorithm). Group LASSO as suggested above would the far superior option over removing/collapsing categories (generally speaking).

Comment: Would including the entire category with my OP method be superior to group LASSO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use group lasso. When you have a categorical variable, with say, $k$ levels, usually represented in a regression model with $k-1$ dummys, that group of $k-1$ dummys *together* is the one variable, and should be included or not as a unit. Group lasso does that.

This have been explained many times on this site, for example [Can I ignore coefficients for non-significant levels of factors in a linear model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24298/can-i-ignore-coefficients-for-non-significant-levels-of-factors-in-a-linear-mode)  and at your other Q here [When finding significance in parts of a categorical variable during stepwise selection, do you include the entire variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/415547/when-finding-significance-in-parts-of-a-categorical-variable-during-stepwise-sel)